# How can I extend Serializer to handle a custom field type?

Tags: 9, entities

I'm trying to extend [Serialization](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/serialization/overview) to get the [JSON Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/json_field) module to return a JSON object instead of stringified JSON.

Goal: When I access an entity that contains a JSON field using JSON:API, I want a JSON object for the field value (currently, the stringified JSON is returned).

I think what I need to do is to extend one of the core normalizers and use it to add a `json_decode()` step.

There is some [documentation on how Serializer handles entities](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/serialization-api/changing-the-way-serializer-handles-entities) but it is out-of-date (last updated in 2017 before JSON:API was part of core, and the current code looks nothing like what is shown.)

I tried extending FieldNormalizer in `/json_field/src/Normalizer/JsonFieldNormalizer.php`.
However, I'm not confident that this is the correct approach, as there is also a FieldItemNormalizer and TypedDataNormalizer.  **To change how a field is output in JSON:API, which class should I extend?**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\json_field\Normalizer;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\json_field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\NativeJSONItem;
use Drupal\jsonapi\JsonApiResource\ResourceObject;
use Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\FieldNormalizer;
use Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\Value\CacheableNormalization;
use Drupal\jsonapi\ResourceType\ResourceType;

class JsonFieldNormalizer extends FieldNormalizer {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected $supportedInterfaceOrClass = NativeJSONItem::class;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function normalize($field, $format = NULL, array $context = []) {
    $field_name = $field->getName();
    \Drupal::logger('json_field')->info("Field has name $field_name");
    assert($field instanceof NativeJSONItem);
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface $field */ $normalized_items = $this->normalizeFieldItems($field, $format, $context);
    assert($context['resource_object'] instanceof ResourceObject);
    return $context['resource_object']->getResourceType()->getFieldByInternalName($field->getName())->hasOne()
      ? array_shift($normalized_items) ?: CacheableNormalization::permanent(NULL)
      : CacheableNormalization::aggregate($normalized_items);
  }
```

And I added the class to `json_field.services.yml`:

```
services:
  json_field.views:
    class: Drupal\json_field\JSONViews
  json_field.normalizer.field.json_field:
    class: Drupal\json_field\Normalizer\JsonFieldNormalizer
    tags:
      - { name: normalizer, priority: 1 }
```

However, after rebuilding the cache and accessing some JSON fields via JSON:API, I don't see anything in the logs, so it seems like the class is not being picked up.

Comment: There are a few things which are inconsistent. You are extending FieldNormalizer but $supportedInterfaceOrClass is that of a field item. So better extend FieldItemNormalizer. You are implementing a jsonapi serializer but the service tag is not `{ name: jsonapi_normalizer, priority: 1 }`.

Comment: @4uk4 Thanks, I originally tried adding it as a `jsonapi_normalizer`, but when I did that, I got the error `LogicException: JSON:API does not allow adding more normalizers!`  I just tried extending FieldItemNormalizer and I'm getting the same problem (no logging is triggered when I access the field through JSON:API).

Comment: OK, I've just tried pointing out the inconsistencies. When they say @internal they really mean it. Reading the comments in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2923779) you probably need to add to your custom field type a custom typed data as well (you can simply extend the  DataDefinition you now have defined in the field properties) and then define a normalizer for this.